# Where can I find a list of food items restricted to bring to Malaysia (for personal consumption)?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, food-and-drink, malaysia

I'll be travelling to Kuala Lumpur soon from India (via Air if that's important) and I was planning on bring some [dried mango pulp](https://www.archanaskitchen.com/aam-papad-recipe-tasty-mango-bars/amp) for personal consumption and also to gift my friends (in a really small quantity though). Is that allowed?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, in my personal experience, Malaysia doesn't enforce much rules on food imports for personal use. They are mostly familiar with the Indian sweets and you won't have any issues. Maximum you can get is to discard that.